# Airport transfer from Stockholm-Arlanda to the central station

Tags: sweden, stockholm

My flight to stockholm Arlanda (ARN) lands at 00:40. I booked a transfert from the airport to my hotel:

Stockholm Arlanda --> Flygbussarna Kista --> Central station

I would like to know if transport is available after midnight (00:40).

I would like to buy a 48 hours transport pass as well. Is it available at the airport ?

Comment: I do not think we can answer this without knowing with whom you booked the transfer. I suspect it would be easiest to ask them directly.

Comment: it's a bus (Bus: FLYGTAXI)

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here.

*Flygbussarna* is a bus service to and from airports in Sweden. From Arlanda airport they operate three routes. They all pick up passengers at three stops at the airport and then take the E4 motorway south, after which they separate. Each route has its own stops in and around central Stockholm.

The most used line is for *Stockholm City* and terminates near the central train station. This route typically departs every 15 minutes or so until about 02:00 and then a few times during the night. The other routes would typically cease at around midnight and resume in the morning. These routes are for *Liljeholmen* and *Brommaplan* respectively. The latter is the only route that passes Kista, which is a district northwest of central Stockholm.

Is Kista where you are going or is it the Stockholm central station? These places are about 12 km apart and are not served by the same bus route.

*Flygtaxi* is a taxi service to and from airports. This is separate and very different from Flygbussarna. Have you bought a bus ticket or booked a taxi? Where is your hotel?

--

You can buy passes for public transit (SL) at the airport. There are no passes for 48 hours, but for 24 hours and 72 hours (as well as for longer periods).